# Delete from textbox not working properly in Mozila Firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, angular-ui-bootstrap, mozilla

In Mozila, Delete key not deleting text in textbox.

Example: Textbox = "abab"

In Mozila, when i click on any textbox(which has some text) cursor will point to starting of text rather than ending point,

Ex: Textbox = "|abab"

and when i press Delete key it will skip first character and delete second, now cursor is pointin to second position.

Ex: Textbox = "a|ab"

Again press Delete key will skip 3rd Character and delte 4th character, now cursor is pointing to third position.

Ex: Textbox = "aa|"

AngularJS, Bootstrap are used....

Comment: Interesting problem. If possible create a simple program on plunker to reproduce this. Many times this kind of problem we could not reproduce. But is is better to try. So other experts can help easily.